# Is it possible to define hoisted curried functions in Livescript?

Tags: partial-application, livescript

How do you define a curried function with the `function` keyword in Livescript?

More succinctly, how can I get this

```
function curry (arg1, arg2)
  do-something arg1, arg2
```

To act like this

```
curry = (arg1, arg2) -->
  do-something arg1, arg2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, and the way curried functions are created in LiveScript currently, it would not be possible to.

Curried functions are created using the `curry$` helper function. We can't call this helper function on a function declaration, because it is a declaration not an expression.